# What is the difference between distro features, machine features and image features ? What dependicies between them?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I am using Yocto project to build a customized distribution to my board. I just want to ask you, what is the difference between **distro features**, **machine features** and **image features** ?

Comment: This question is [primarily opinion-based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and will most probably be closed. Read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find more information.

Comment: @Matthew I disagree, Yocto configuration (distro/image/machine/...) is quite hard to understand and this question does not raise a `primarily opinion-based` issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yocto uses features as a means to figure out which libraries, utilities and kernel modules to include in the image.

There is some overlap between the three feature categories (especially distro- and image features), and it is not always obvious where to look for a particular feature. For example, *api-documentation* is a distro feature, while *doc-pkgs* is an image feature.

So these definitions are my own, check out the [reference manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.7/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-features) for more details.

Machine features are related to the hardware that the image is built for. For instance, the *rtc* feature specifies that the hardware has a built-in real-time clock, while the *bluetooth* feature indicates that the hardware supports bluetooth.

Distro features select broader categories of software support, though there is some overlap with machine features. Examples of distro-level features include *ipv6*, *systemd* and *x11*.

Image features typically (but not always, see *splash* or *read-only-rootfs*) are used to enable functionality useful for debugging and diagnosing issues. For example, *allow-empty-password* configures SSH servers to allow root login without password, and *dbg-pkgs* installs debug symbols for all packages in the image.